# Jordan measure of this set

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I have a set: $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\, 1\le x_1\le e,\, 0\le x_2\le \ln x_1\}$. Im trying to understand: is it Jordan measurable or not. I tried to plot this set on plane, but i still can't understand what is $\mu_{*}$ and $\mu^{*}$. Please, give me some hints

Comment: A bounded set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is Jordan measurable if $\chi_E$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @d.k.o but how to solve without Riemann, Lebesgue?